# Question on Proof of Set of Sets Proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement regarding a set of sets $\mathscr{A}$:

$$x\notin \bigcap \mathscr{A} \; \text{iff there exists A} \in \mathscr{A} \; \text{such that} \; x \notin A$$

Here is what I have so far:

$$x\notin\bigcap \mathscr{A}$$
$$\text{if it is not the case that} \;x \in \bigcap \mathscr{A} $$
$$\text{if it is not the case that} \; x \in A \; \text{for all A} \in \mathscr{A}$$

I am a bit confused now though. 
Couldn't there be some $x \in A$ such that $A \in \mathscr{A}$, but that x does not belong to all sets in $\mathscr{A}$? In which case, wouldn't this then mean $x\notin\cap \mathscr{A}$?

Comment: What does it mean "it is not the case that $n > 1$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$" ? That there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that not-$(n>1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have managed to confuse yourself by putting the quantifier last. When you say
"It is not the case that $x\in A$ for all $A$" it is unclear whether you mean

> It is not the case that ($x\in A$ for all $A$).

or

> (It is not the case that $x\in A$) for all $A$.

These are different meanings and you want only one of them. The confusion goes away if you follow the usual mathematical syntax (which is this way for a reason!) and put *everything that modifies a single claim*, including quantifiers and negations, *before* that claim. Then you get

> It is not the case that for all $A$ we have $x\in A$.

which is unambiguous, and hopefully known to be equivalent to

> There is an $A$ such that it is not the case that $x\in A$.

Comment: Thank you! This clarified it well